# How can I get all my website pages to show in the Word Press dashboard?

Tags: page-specific-settings

I recently migrated my website from GoDaddy to WordPress. I need to add new pages to my existing site, which is now managed by word press. I can't the pages on word press dashboard, so how can view all page in my home page?

Regards,
John

Comment: Are you referring to pages you created somehow outside of WordPress? Then no, you can't show those in the WordPress dashboard. The WordPress dashboard will only show pages created with WordPress.

Comment: Please correct your grammar above so we can understand what you are trying to say. Maybe elaborate a little more.